# How can non-Caucasians avoid suspicious looks when traveling in the West?

Tags: local-customs, discrimination

Being an Arab with Arabian looks, after September 11 things have changed dramatically when Arabs or people with similar looks (Indians, Pakistanis, Turkish, Kurdish, Iranians...etc) go to the west side of the world (Europe and North America).

Some people just keep giving you 'that look' and I am not talking about racism here. I will give you an example.

In one of my flights from New York to Los Angeles (6 hrs flight) me and my friend were the only Arabs onboard a 767 wide body aircraft (around 200 passengers). Whenever I stood up to open the overhead compartment to grab something from my bag I would have that look from people. People would stop eating or reading or smiling and just keep looking at me till I am done and I am sure they are expecting me to take a bomb out or something like that!  If any one else stood up and opened a compartment no one would even care!

Same exact looks were also found in a train from Paris to Amsterdam. The funny part is when we arrive people who gave me those looks would smile at me and some even would talk or ask questions...it is like they are thanking me for not killing them :)

Another time I was taking a helicopter tour in New York, and when we were onboard there were two young American ladies and they were kinda shocked to see me and my friend onboard, They literally were making prayers and looking at us! And again after we landed they were talking to us and even took pictures together!

Another example would be in restaurants specially fancy ones, malls or museums.

Another funny thing, my friend's name is `Osama` and he has all funny kinds of treatment because of his name. People sometime can be so superficial and treat someone in a suspicious way just because his name.

For me it's funny but not always! Sometimes this bothers me a lot specially when you are the one being picked up from hundreds of people for a random check from a police officer and the way they deal with you sometimes is totally weird, they treat you like a potential threat while all you were doing is having some fun!

**What's the best way to avoid this?**

Comment: @littleadv I disagree with you, if Arabs destroyed two towers killing 5,000 people caused this, Then following your concept we should think the same of US citizens because they have destroyed two Muslim countries killing few millions.. This is a wrong way of thinking I have to say and I totally disagree... Religion has nothing here and I do not recall mentioning about it.. and FYI not all Arabs are muslims and I never said that I'm muslim...

Comment: @HaLaBi I might be wrong, but Americans are not exactly adored around the globe. I've lived in several countries, out of these the only country in which Americans were liked by the local population was the US. I agree with you that this may be the wrong way of thinking, but that's the way the humans think. We generalize and try to sort things into patterns. That's how it works, you can rant and complain, but its not going to change any time soon.

Comment: As a westerner living in Japan, I totally understand where you're coming from. While it's not necessarily negative feedback I get here, I feel the Japanese "well intentioned racism" all the time. You just gotta get used to it, unfortunately. :)

Comment: You don't have to look Middle Eastern and be in North America or Western Europe for this to happen. I've seen black friends from Nigeria and England suffer this in Mexico City. I've even been subject to it myself as a white westerner in indigenous villages in Mexico, but also to a lesser extent in other areas. I'm lucky though in that I know it only happens for brief times in specific places so I can see how it feels for other people but for me it's always easy to get away from it by going back to a bigger place. It's not so easy for others though.

Comment: @deceze What's "well intentioned racism"?

Comment: @Andrew The well meaning we-know-we-are-different-by-which-we-mean-you-are-different-and-you-really-don't-have-to-understand-all-of-our-complicated-culture-but-we-still-welcome-you-by-the-way-when-will-you-be-leaving kind of way of typically treating "gaijin"... :)

Comment: @deceze I hadn't noticed any well-meaning discrimination in my three weeks in Japan, though I did come across some [just following orders](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6705/324) discrimination. Maybe I was just too oblivious to notice!

Comment: i had a little of this in a Chicago subway, while I wanted to have a picture with cute kid who "honestly" called as JackSparrow from "Pirates of the Caribbean". But his mom refused it with "blah blah ..." :)

Comment: @kmonsoor In that side of the world, it is not common and not normal to do such a thing.. unlike our side of the world, where you can hug and kiss almost any child and take photos.. its more of a culture thing..

Comment: @HaLaBi Discrimination exists everywhere, even before 9/11, thats just the way it is eg An American said to me about 4 years ago, he was totally shocked at the prejudice he saw against Eastern Europeans when he first came to live in the UK approx 10 years ago (also the same time that a numbers of countries  joined the EU). He couldn't understand it. I responded by saying you are from America, you are from Land of Immigrants. In Europe people believe there country is their own, and as such discrimination exists (unfortunately).

Comment: Bear in mind that not everywhere in the West is the same in this respect. Here in London everyone will assume you're a Londoner regardless of skin tone, appearance and language, so long as you: a) stand on the right on the escalators, and b) let other people get off the train before you try to get on it.

Comment: You will have to live with it. It happens to white caucasians too if you are in a non western country. People are just shallow.

Comment: Last time I was taking a flight from Morocco to Europe (Basel). A group of 3 men wearing traditional muslim clothes (I guess that's what it was) & wearing long beards turned up at the gate. 90% of passengers were from arabic background (Moroccan roots most likely), most of them were staring at those 3 men, not in a nice way. As you guessed, the flight went well & it was all a big prejudice. I found interesting the fact that the people victims of prejudices (ppl with arabic roots) from us (western ppl) showed the same prejudices, towards those 3 men, that we (western ppl) have against them.

Comment: @AE : but London is a very unique place in the world. It's full of... everything: european, middle-eastern, asians, south-americans, north americans, africans & more. In London, being "different" is being like everyone. That's what I love abt that city. Maybe a good pit-stop for travellers being sick of racism/strong-prejudices ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I can't say that I completely understand your situation (I am, after all, of European descent), but you should not be surprised to find out that

### Some people <strike>are stupid</strike> have prejudices

I have indeed been treated sometimes differently for being Eastern European (and proud of it!), and the thing that I found works best is to just ignore them and pretend that you don't know what they are doing. Acting in a way that reinforces their stereotypes won't help, neither is being defensive, so be very polite (the more annoying they are, the more polite you should be) with the people you meet and try to "behave like them" in certain situations.

In 99% of the time, the prejudices stem from the fact that they have never (or rarely) seen a people of your ethnic descent *in vivo*, and all their opinions towards members of certain ethnic groups come from mass media and other prejudiced people.

All being said,here are some things that might help:

- **Appearance**. While people of ethnic origin other than European are common for many European countries, clothing style is pretty much uniform all over Europe. Traditional clothing is virtually not seen, and wearing it would definitely cause more raised eyebrows than it would otherwise. Please note that I'm not trying to denigrate the clothing style of a particular culture, but the train of thought of many people goes along the lines of `looks different`->`is different`->`is unknown`->`I don't like them`.
- **Behaviour**. Be polite with people, even if they are annoying jingoistic pricks. Smile at them when making inadvertent eye contact.

  - Don't try to start an argument with them that you are a normal guy and just because you look or are named in a particular way doesn't mean you behave like that. Don't answer back. You are not going to win this one. Best tactics is to smile and ignore them, even if you are right. Especially when you are right.
  - Ignore their suspicious look and hushed remarks aimed at you -- take the moral high ground and pretend these things don't affect you.
  - Certain religious practices tend to alarm ignorant people, so avoid conducting them in the presence of others if possible.
- **Language**. If you are in the presence of people that don't know your language, try not to use it when you are talking to your friend and other people are also part of the discussion. I always switch automatically to English in such situations, even if the people that don't understand the language are a minority. This shows consideration to the others and demonstrates you don't have second thoughts and are not talking behind their backs. Of course, if it's only you and your friend, you can talk in any language you like, but as soon as another people join the conversation, it's common courtesy to switch to English (or other language common for the group you are in). Of course, other people should be doing exactly the same when you are in your presence, but sadly this won't happen nearly as often.

---

And now, some of my favourite personal examples of overturned stereotypes: I have a friend of Iraqi descent who is a fervent Catholic, has been to Jerusalem more than a few times and goes to church regularly. At the same time, another friend of mine of Bosnian descent is a Muslim, although you can never tell from the way he looks and behaves. And finally, yet another of my friends from Ethiopia made a furor at a certain defense contractor company when he appeared with dreadlocks and baggy pants on a project presentation, and proceeded to blow their minds with his competence. They were utterly confused and later my friend told me that this was one of the most satisfying moments of his life.

Comment: +1 for the language. Even if people "like to hear" your native language (ie. French), it can get very frustrating for some people not to understand what you say, even though they are not even part of the conversation.

Comment: I really do not understand whatsoever the recommendation of not talking in my home language so bystanders/strangers can understand my private conversation...

Answer (score 11):

Namaste!

In my experience, and my opinion, behaving in a friendly and respectful AND assertive manner goes a long way.

I am a what people would call a "white South African", and have travelled in Turkey, Greece, Egypt and Indonesia, to name a few. In spite of dressing modestly (long skirts, arms completely covered and hair covered) I was constantly physically harrased when in Turkey, and definitely stared at everywhere I travelled, so I can empathise with your dilema. The perception of many people is that all western women are loose, or sexually available, and easy. I had to stand up for myself or be abused.

Now I realise that we are talking about separate issues here, but the bottom line is that most people are ignorant. I found out that by talking to people, telling them about my beliefs and showing my individuality, let them see that they could not put me in a box with all their other generalisations. They began to respect me once they knew where I was coming from. If you see someone staring at you, give them a friendly hello and take it from there. On the other hand, do not put up with any harrasment.

Not all of us in the west are ignorant and predjudiced. There are some spiritual and non judgemental people here too.

I wish you joyous and pleasant travelling experiences, and maybe you would like to visit Cape Town someday.

(By the way, I also had to convince a lot of people that not all white South Africans are racist, we are usually automatically branded that way!)

Answer (score 8):

While a different type of attention, as a blond Caucasian people would stare when I was walking around South America, and point, and you'd hear "gringo, gringo" and often some choice words after that.  A few cheery words back in my awful Spanish would get a laugh and they'd carry on as per normal.

I had a friend who was of Sri Lankan descent, who grew a beard in London.  We came back from Norway once, and left him alone for a minute in the airport.  As he stood there, two policemen immediately came up and started questioning him, and did a background check.  Once that was done they were all friendly, and it could be random, but it made you wonder.

When it comes down to it, we all have our prejudices, warranted or not, big or small.  And we have to realise that so do other people.  We judge on appearance, on name, on voice, on what they're wearing.  And it's stupid, yes, but this is how we have survived for millenia - by making snap judgements.  It's a built in thing.

Of course, in today's modern society, we have the freedom to self-evaluate and realise that these are often unfounded.  Partly it's the media's fault, partly stereotypes.  Unfortunately, not everyone does this, or may not do it at first.

As such, you have two options. The first option is to just accept it and ignore it.  I got used to being stared at, and had fun with it - wave at people, walk up to those making comments and use them to ask for directions or whatever.  Diffuse things.

The second option is to try and reduce the differences between you and them.  This puts people at ease.  Just saying hello and having them hear a friendly voice helps.  If you are ok doing so, dressing more like the locals to fit in.  With people being scared on a helicopter ride, ask where they're from etc, and maybe take a photo with them early on to show that you're also just another excited tourist.

Something I've found is that the more travelled backpackers - often (but not always) - tend to be more familiar, easier at making friends - mainly because they've realised people everywhere are just that - people, for the most part trying to live a happy life with friends and family.

Of course there are a small few who are narrow-minded enough that you won't be able to change them.  Be friendly towards them anyway, but accept that it's not necessarily worth the effort, and some will always be hostile or suspicious.

Comment: I myself am an european, and while studying in the UK, I just made sure I had always extra-short air, and no beard so I would blend in.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to preface this with saying that I don't agree with the prejudice but I acknowledge the fact that it exists and with that painful point in mind here are my thoughts and advice.

The bad news is without actual interaction, it's really hard to change somebody's silent prejudice. To put people at ease around you that you are not going to actually speak to, it helps to reduce cultural differences. To get fewer looks in America, dress the way a responsible American of your age would and learn some of the local customs. As a warning, don't dress as a caricature of your target culture. Your goal should be to blend more then anything.

For somebody sitting next to you, strike up a conversation and find some common ground. Be sensitive to the fact that they may just not want to talk at all. Personally I don't mind small talk but on a long flight I prefer the movie.

Humans are naturally suspicious of things that are different. Your goal is to reduce the perceived differences to a degree that triggers the behavior from strangers that is tolerable to you. The longer you're going to interact with them the more effort you will need to put into building a connection. This will work about 80% of the time. The other 20% would probably require too much work for it to be worth your energy.

Comment: trying to blend in too much can also raise suspicion. After all, that's what terrorists do, try to blend in so they go unnoticed in their target societies... It's effectively a no-win situation. Live with the idea you're going to have to have to do more than natives to get people to trust you. As you said, it's the same everywhere. If Europeans notice it less it's because most of the world will pretend to like them just to get them to part with their money, not because they actually do like them.

Answer (score 1):

I am from a super minority and travel 4 times a month and based on my experience:

1 - First look clean and healthy (no red/yellow eyes)

2 - Pack clean and feel free to use the post office to send over things that could irritate the custom officer

3 - Prepare your documents and fill all forms before getting to the counter

4 - Look at your passport as he/she checks it (do not look at them in the eyes - few will know that)

5 - Travel light is a standard.

Comment: Red eyes = too tired or drunk, yellow eyes = drug usage. This is not a rule but it is how people would tend to think.

Comment: Can you explain number 4?

Comment: What's a 'super minority'?

Comment: I assume #4 is a way to defer / submit to the custom official's authority and show you're not challenging them. I do the same thing when I get pulled over by a cop and cross my hands on the steering wheel. You don't do it because you're weak, you're just choosing to avoid any pointless confrontation.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I know this is an old question, but a super minority can be a minority group with enough members to block what the majority want. (i.e. the US Republican party is the minority party, but has enough to filibuster); it can also mean a minority in power (white South Africans during apartheid years.)

Comment: @CGCampbell Or it could just as easily refer to a very minor minority.